# Can't boot into Windows 10(Dual-Boot)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, bios, 19.04

[image]

Hello, Since today, I am not able to boot windows 10 for some reason. Yesterday everything worked as normally.. I have ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10 on the same SSD installed (240GB). As I start the laptop, I get automatically booted into ubuntu although Windows 10 is set as boot option #1, so I tried disabling ubuntu and restartet my laptop again, but then I get sent to the BIOS menu. I also tried with F8 and then boot windows as you can see on the image, but nothing happes.

Does anyone know what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
Can you not boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu? Same key you used to select flash drive to install Ubuntu, often f10 or f12. Grub only boots working Windows and if fast start-up is on,  then grub will not boot Windows.

Comment: @oldfred Hello, unfortunately I decided to just reinstall windows, which damaged the partition of ubuntu, which is why I also had to reinstall ubuntu aswell. I saw this comment too late.. sorry